# Flutter deep linking always opens a new application rather than the same one - Windows

Tags: flutter, windows, macos

I have a fairly basic flutter application that opens when a user clicks a specific link via deep linking. I have created applications for the windows and Mac version, but for some reason on Mac when you click the link it continues from the previous application session, whereas on windows every time you click the link a new flutter application window opens. Does anyone have any idea how to force windows to act in the same way as Mac?